# One rest endpoint works just fine, other gives CORs error

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, cors

I have a react client app and django server app. React app is running on port `9997` and server API is available on port `9763`. Frontend is able to access some APIs while some APIs are failing with error:

[image]

As you can see first URL works, but second does not:

[image]

**API that works**

React code:

```
import axios from "axios";

// ... 

async getRestEndpoint1() {
    let url = '/app/api/rest_endpoint1/'
    const axiosInstance = axios.create();
    try {
        const response = await axiosInstance.get(url,
            {
                params: {
                    'format': 'json',
                    'propId': this.props.routeProps.match.params.propId
                }
            }
        )
        return response.data;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

Django REST code:

```
def getHttpJsonResponse(obj):
    resp = json.dumps(obj, default=str)
    return HttpResponse(resp, content_type="application/json", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

@api_view(http_method_names=['GET'])    
def getRestEndpoint1(request):
    entityId = request.GET['entityId']
    headers = EntityObject.objects.filter(entity_id=entityId).all()
    resp = []
    for header in headers:
        resp.append({ 'id': entity.id, 'subEntityName': header.subEntity_name})
    return getHttpJsonResponse(resp)
```

Response Headers:

[image]

**API that does not work**

React code:

```
import axios from "axios";

// ... 

async getRestEndpoint2() {
    let url = '/app/api/rest_endpoint2/'
    const axiosInstance = axios.create();
    try {
        const response = await axiosInstance.get(url,
            {
                params: {
                    'format': 'json'
                }
            }
        )
        return response.data;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

Django code:

```
@api_view(http_method_names=['GET'])
def getRestEndpoint2(request):
    # business logic

    return getHttpJsonResponse(respStatsJson)
```

Both APIs are in same `views.py` file and have similar paths added to `urls.py`:

```
path('api/rest_endpoint1/', getRestEndpoint1 , name='rest_endpoint1'),
path('api/rest_endpoint2/', getRestEndpoint2 , name='rest_endpoint2')
```

Response headers:

[image]

My `settings.py` has ollowing lines:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://10.129.131.6:9997',
)

if DEBUG:
    CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

So, everything just works on my local machine in debug mode. But when I checkout that branch on remote server, build docker image, and start the container, above behavior occurs. What I am missing here?

Comment: Verify with the browser "Network" tab that CORS headers are being returned; or, rather, that they are *not* being returned, because if they were you wouldn't have the problem. That will confirm that your problem is with your Django configuration (or deployment or something).

Comment: A quick fix would be adding this plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-unblock/lfhmikememgdcahcdlaciloancbhjino?hl=en to chrome and enable it

Comment: @Bhargav that chrome extension seems useful. With CORS unblocked I am getting error code 500. Seems there is some server side processing error which was sending response without `Access-Control-Allowed-Origin` header. Also I have added screenshots of the reponse headers and error to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Status code 500 should have hinted me that something was wrong at server side. Instead I interpreted that it was due to CORS error. Pure CORS error does not change HTTP status code as it is set be server. So status code should be `HTTP 200 OK` in case of no server side processing error.

It turns out there were some environment related issues that was causing some REST endpoints fail while some were working on remote server. The failed ones were getting ended up in status code 500 followed by CORS error. No such environment issues existed in my local machine. So everything was working fine locally.

Checking server side app logs helped.